# How to detect output change of hand-wave sensor in MCU (Nano clone)

Tags: microcontroller

I have 12V powered hand-wave sensor (U2 on the image) and some Chinese "Nano" clone powered from same source. On the nano I want to use some pin (P1 on the image) to read U2 output.

I do not know how to connect this, because the primary problem I see is that the output from U2 is 0V vs 12V and P1 is 5V.

[image: illustrative image]

The image is illustrative only, it is not complete schematic at all. I need to solve that "?". As you can see, I have tried some NPN transistor as switch (resistors are not shown). It worked when base was connected to 12V from source or to the ground.

BUT it does NOT work when using U2. I found out, that the U2 output has "common +" or whatever it is called. It means that when output is 1, the voltage of out- goes to 0 and when the output is 0, the voltage of "out-" goes to 12V. The voltage of "out+" stays same 12V. I took these measurements with reference GND.

This seems like trivial thing and yet I am lost, but I hope somebody can help. I am real amateur, made some "digital" things using 5V powered plain AVRs, but I am lost at this voltage conversions. Have some stuff like LM139 or NE555 in the drawer if that can help somehow.

Comment: Guessing - the out + and - may be internally connected by a transistor.  If you ground the - output then the + output could pull down against an external pull-up resistor to +5.  But if you’re uncertain about the internals of the sensor, do a few experiments first to try to characterise it.  Rather than just connecting things to power rails etc, use a resistor (maybe 1k) and measure the current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just some ideas:

1. Use a voltage divider at Out- to get 12V down to 5V.
2. Use the internal pull up of the Nano and put a n-channel MOSFET (or the NPN transistor you currently have, but with base resistor!) directly at Out-.
3. Use the voltage between Out+/Out- to drive an optocoupler to pull the GPIO low (internal pullup must be enabled).

In any case, the signal would have to be inverted in software.

Comment: Yes, the optocoupler was my first idea too, but I do not have any in the drawer :) So tried voltage divider, but still did not work, until I put some 10k load resistor between out+ and out-. Then everything works, perfect.